# Better way to work on a Rails gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Hi guys sometimes I work a gem and sometimes to develop this gem I need a Rails application.
Actually when I do this I make my gem in the **vendor/plugins/my_gem/** directory and I do all work in this directory.

May be there is other way to do this, more cleaner (plugin like this won't work in rails 4.0).

Answer (score 0):

I normally work have a separate, version-controlled projects for every custom gem that I work on. I normally create gems using Bundler, although there are other options. I specify rake as a development dependency in the `my_gem.gemspec`. After I'm done writing code and specs in the gem, I normally assign it a new version, then run:

```
# cd/to/my_gem
bundle exec rake build # build a gem
ruby -S gem install ./pkg/my_gem-0.0.1.gem # install it locally

# cd/to/app_using_gem/
gem unpack my_gem -v 0.0.1 --target ./vendor/gems # vendorize gem
```

I think this way is cleaner than modifying code in `vendor/plugins/my_gem/`